# SQL Plus Error At Line 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to list each order, list the order ID, order date, customer ID, customer first name, customer last name, sales rep ID, sales rep first name, and sales rep last name; sort by order ID; Format the order date as “mm/dd/yy”.

Here is my UPDATED Code!

```
SELECT Order_ID as Order_ID, to_char(Order_Date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as Date, OR.Cust_ID as Cust_ID, 
Cust_FName as Cust_FName, Cust_LName as Cust_LName, SR.Sales_Rep_ID as Sales_Rep_ID,  
Sales_Rep_FName as Sales_Rep_FName, Sales_Rep_LName as SalesRepLName
FROM ORDER_arb OR, CUSTOMER_arb C, SALES_REP_arb SR
WHERE OR.Cust_ID = C.Cust_ID AND
C.Sales_Rep_ID = SR.Sales_Rep_ID
ORDER BY Order_ID;
```

I am receiving this error: 
UPDATE!!
Error at Line 1: FROM keyword not found where expected

I would appreciate any input.
Thanks

Comment: Based on the syntax highlighting in the text above, might it have something to do with using the "OR" keyword in a location it is not expected (i.e., as a table alias)?

Comment: to_char() is an Oracle function.  Q: Are you talking to an Oracle database?

Comment: FoggyDay- Yes it is an oracle database

Comment: OK - then most Oracle client tools (including SQLPlus) should show you *where* on "Line 1" the error is occurring. Could you tell us?

Comment: Just added a new update to the code

Comment: Please remove 'OR' alias and 'Date' keyword  as mentioned in below answer. If you still need to use Date word as alias, use double quotes with Date word as "Date"

Comment: AWESOME- Just got everything to work. THANKS EVERYONE!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Please change 'OR' to 'ORD'  and 'as Date' to 'as OrderDate'.
Because DATE is a keyword in oracle. and OR alias seems working different than wen think. If you still needs to use column alias sa Date, please use with double quotes as "Date"

```
SELECT ORD.Order_ID as Order_ID, to_char(ORD.Order_Date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as OrderDate, ORD.Cust_ID as Cust_ID, 
   C.Cust_FName as Cust_FName, C.Cust_LName as Cust_LName, SR.Sales_Rep_ID as Sales_Rep_ID,
   SR.Sales_Rep_FName as Sales_Rep_FName, SR.Sales_Rep_LName as SalesRepLName
FROM ORDER_arb ORD, CUSTOMER_arb C, SALES_REP_arb SR
WHERE ORD.Cust_ID = C.Cust_ID 
  AND C.Sales_Rep_ID = SR.Sales_Rep_ID
ORDER BY Order_ID;
```